# Query on tag with wildcard doesn’t match tags with a number

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-watching, wildcards

The interesting tag [`[ejb*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ejb~) (<- that's a link) should match `[ejb]` **and** `[ejb3]` but does only match `[ejb]`.

The interesting tag [`[jee*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jee~) (<- that's a link) should match `[jee5]` and `[jee6]` but doesn't match anything.

The interesting tag [`[hbm*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hbm~) (<- that's a link) should match `[hbm]`, `[hbm2java]`, `[hbm2ddl]` but does only match `[hbm]`.

**Update:** Actually, this question seems to be a `[status-bydesign]` candidate:  wildcards requests use 4 characters at least (or the wildcard appear to be ignored). This would explain the mentioned behavior. Is there a previous question that confirms this rule? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for client-side JavaScript wildcard tag matching uses `*`.

The syntax for server-side SQL wildcard tag matching uses `~`. On the server side we restrict this to minimum 4 character matches to prevent too much explosion in matches.

Comment: I'll take that as authoritative answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The star is ignored; use [tilde (~)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhiber~) as a wildcard.  (You have to use at least 4 characters, apparently, so ejb~ won't work.)

Comment: On second reading, are you talking about interesting tags as displayed on the homepage instead of searching?  If so, I'll delete this.

Comment: As displayed (my question includes the corresponding server side requests with tilde). However, the 4 characters rules seems to be the explanation. Is it a publicly known rule? Anyway, I think I'll accept this answer but maybe you could rephrase (remove?) the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`ej[b]~`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ej%5Bb%5D~), [`je[e]~`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/je%5Be%5D~), [`hb[m]~`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hb%5Bm%5D~). Basically work-around for those with numbers.

Comment: Thanks. This works indeed, but it seems I can't use this syntax in interesting tags.